# Quick VBA syntax

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need to solve this task by adding a VBA syntax for the following:

In Column A I have random numbers between 1 and 7. On Column B I need to insert "a day" for rows equal to 1 and "several days" for 2 to 7.

**Notes:** I know this will be much easier by adding a simple IF formula, but the idea is to have a VBA macro for this one. However, I am not really sure how the syntax should look.

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149849/discussion-on-question-by-andon-key-quick-vba-syntax); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

You can use the Function directly on the sheet as a formula if you want - `=DayOrDays(A2)`

or you can use the procedure that calls the function for each cell in your defined range and places the result one cell to the right (`OFFSET(,1)`).

```
Public Sub AddToSheet()
    Dim TargetRng As Range
    Set TargetRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A19")
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In TargetRng
        Cell.Offset(, 1) = DayOrDays(Cell) 'Offset(,1) is one cell to the right of Target.
    Next Cell
End Sub

Public Function DayOrDays(Target As Range) As Variant
    Dim Cell As Range
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If IsNumeric(Target) Then
            If Target = 1 Then DayOrDays = "a day" Else DayOrDays = "several days"
        Else
            DayOrDays = CVErr(xlErrValue) 'Value isn't a number.
        End If
    Else
        DayOrDays = CVErr(xlErrRef) 'Reference is more than one cell.
    End If
End Function
```

[image]